# How do I create a list in Oz?

Tags: oz, mozart

I'm trying to create a list in [Oz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oz_programming_language) using the following code:

```
local Loop10 Xs in
   proc {Loop10 I}
      Xs={List.append Xs I}
      if I == 10 then skip
      else
     {Browse I}
     {Loop10 I+1}
      end
      {Browse Xs}
   end
{Loop10 0}
end
```

The [Mozart compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozart_Programming_System) shows that the code is accepted, but no Browse window opens up. All I'm trying to do is create a list in Oz.

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure that that's what you want, but to create a list of all whole numbers between X and Y (inclusive) you could do:

```
local
   fun {Loop From To}
      if From > To
      then nil
      else From | {Loop From+1 To}
      end
   end
in
   {Browse {Loop 0 10}} % Displays: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually stumbled upon the same method myself. Although in order to return a proper list the second argument to Loop must be To|nil so that the list is always terminated with a nil.

thanks.

Comment: In my opinion, it's more secure and more logical to do `if From < To then nil` because you can give a "To" less than "From" and get nil (and not an infinite list like in the above program)

Comment: @yakoudbz Good point (except that it should be `>`, not `<`). Done.

Answer (score 5):

Also the reason why you don't get any browser window is because the evaluation thread suspend due to this line:

```
Xs={List.append Xs I}
```

As it was previously mentioned a variable can only be assigned once but there is something else that is wrong with this line.
You attempt to append `Xs` to I but `Xs` is still unbound. The thread thus suspends until a value has been assign to `Xs`.

Enter this interactively:

```
declare Xs in
{Browse {List.append Xs [2 3 4]}}
```

As you see nothing happens, no browser opens. Now enter this:

```
Xs= [1]
```

Since `Xs` becomes bound it unlocks the first evaluation "thread" and the browser will pop-up.

P.S. Sorry for the late answer, I just got interested in Oz :P

Comment: This worked when I replaced `List.append` with `Append`