# Function and procedure behave differently with the same code in Mozart Oz?

Tags: function, procedure, oz, mozart

I try printing out the Fibonacci sequence in Oz using 2 approach : function and procedure using Emac as editor.
Procedure goes here :

```
declare 
fun {Fibo N} 
   case N of 
      1 then 1 
   [] 2 then 1
[] M then {Fibo (M-1)} + {Fibo (M-2)} 
   end 
end 
declare
proc {Loop K}
   if K ==1 then  {Browse K}
   else
      {Loop K-1}
       {Browse {Fibo K}}
   end
end
{Loop 10}
```

and function:

```
declare 
fun {Fibo N} 
   case N of 
      1 then 1 
   [] 2 then 1
[] M then {Fibo (M-1)} + {Fibo (M-2)} 
   end 
end
declare
fun {Loo L}
   if L ==1 then  {Browse L}
   else
      {Loo L-1}
       {Browse {Fibo L}}
   end
end
{Loo 10}
```

The problem is the only Procedure "Loop" works. Result is:

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
```

Function "Loo" doesn't and it throws some hard-to-understand errors:

```
%********************** static analysis error *******************
%**
%** illegal arity in application
%**
%** Arity found:          1
%** Expected:             2
%** Application (names):  {Loo _}
%** Application (values): {<P/2> _<optimized>}
%** in file "Oz", line 13, column 6

%********************** static analysis error *******************
%**
%** illegal arity in application
%**
%** Arity found:          1
%** Expected:             2
%** Application (names):  {Loo _}
%** Application (values): {<P/2> 10}
%** in file "Oz", line 17, column 0
%** ------------------ rejected (2 errors)
```

I still don't know why. As I think function and procedure has similar effect in OZ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions must be called either with function call syntax:

```
_ = {Loo 10}
```

or alternatively with an additional parameter to receive the value:

```
{Loo 10 _}
```

`_` is pronounced "don't care" and means that the value of the variable is not needed.

Also, functions must return a value by having an expression as the last part of every branch. So your fixed `Loo` function would look like this:

```
fun {Loo L}
   if L == 1 then
      {Browse L}
      unit
   else
      _ = {Loo L-1}
      {Browse {Fibo L}}
      unit
   end
end
_ = {Loo 10}
```

However, using a function for looping like this does not make much sense if you don't have anything interesting to return. Maybe what you really want is to [build a list and return it as the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463464/how-do-i-create-a-list-in-oz)?

Comment: thnks. it works. I wanna ask what is the task which "unit" does?

Comment: @silentbang: `unit` is just a value. Writing "unit" as the last part of a branch returns it. You could use any other value (like `42` or `"hello"`), but by convention `unit` is used when no meaningful value is available.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in the definition of `Loo` at line 13.

You're calling `Loop`, which does not exist. I assume you should be calling `Loo`.

**UPDATE:** What you are seeing is due to the difference between functions and procedures; functions always return values, procedures don't. You are giving a single argument to `Loo` (`K-1`), but `Loo` needs two arguments; one input variable and one variable to capture the return value. Oz tells you this by saying that you're applying the wrong arity to `Loo` (you're applying one argument (unary) when you should be applying two arguments (binary)).

This means you have to assign the return value to a variable as well. Do one of:

1. `A = {Loo K-1}`
2. `{Loo K-1 A}`

`A` is the variable to which the return value will be assigned. A common convention for cases where you don't care what the function returns is to use `_` as the return variable name.